# a target has a dependency which that dependency itself is not a target

Tags: linux, makefile

Here is a tutorial for make file in Linux: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Here is a make file example:

```
all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
    g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

For me this line is confusing `main.o: main.cpp`
What does it mean? As I understand, it means target `main.o` has a `main.cpp` dependency. But there is no target with `main.cpp`
It means a target (`main.o`) has a dependency (`main.cpp`) which that dependency (`main.cpp`) itself is not a target. So what is it (`main.cpp`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main.cpp` is a *file*.

From the extension we expect it to be a c++ source file, and the associated rule suggest that this is the case.

The rule will be exectuted any time that `main.cpp` is newer than `main.o` (which is also a file).

Comment: But what does it mean? It means this target will run if that file exists in current folder? Dependency can be a file? if yes what does it mean?

Comment: Well, my stealth edit covers that, but I'll say it again the rule will execute if `main.o` has a modification date later than any of it's file dependencies (in this case there is only `main.cpp`). This is the primary use case for make.

Comment: As I underestand a dependency could be a target or a file name. If it is a target it should be run at first, and if it is a file name it means that existing of that file is a precondition for that target to be run

Comment: I got it now! Make checks the modification times of the files, and whenever a file becomes “newer” than something that depends on it, (in other words, modified) it runs the compiler accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`main.cpp` is your source code.  The fact that there is no target for `main.cpp` just means that Make has no way to generate that file.  You are expected to create it yourself.

Comment: It means this target will run if that file exists in current folder?

Comment: It means that if Make needs the file `main.cpp` and it does not exist, then Make will fail because it does not know how to create it.